# Return the largest number in an array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to get my program to print the largest value from an array of integers.
cVoteA is the vote count for a specific candidate(cNameA).
The values for cVoteA and cNameA are input manually using  GUI.getInt

Every time I run the program, it will print only the first name and I can't figure out how to get it to print the largest.

```
//WinnerM value method
    public static String WinnerM(String cNameA[], int cVoteA[], int thresh, int winner)
    {
        int total = cVoteA[0]; //Declare the total variable and set it to 0
        int iv = 0;
        for (iv = 0; iv < cVoteA.length; iv++)
        {
            if(cVoteA[iv] > total)
            {
                winner = cVoteA[iv];
            }
        }
        return cNameA[winner]; //Return candidate name
    }
```

Here is where the method is called

```
//FIND WINNER
        int winner = 0;
        WinnerM(cNameA, cVoteA, thresh, winner);

        System.out.println("Winner     " + "          " + cNameA[winner]); //Print Winner and the name of the candidate with most votes
```

Any help is appreciated

Using Java language with BlueJ

Comment: `System.out.println("Winner: " + WinnerM(cNameA, cVoteA, thresh, winner));`

Comment: That prints the last name now but not the one with the largest value

Comment: Then you "search" is broken. As mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize the variable for the maximum position of cVotaA (`winner`) to the first array element.
2. Compare `cVoteA(iv)` to the maximum cVoteA so far, `cVoteA(winner)`.
3. When you find a new maximum, save the subscript (`iv`) to `winner`.
4. Use the subscript of the maximum (`winner`) to output the value and name.

Comment: i honestly don't understand programming lingo so would it be possible if you could tell me the lines of code i need to change or tell me in a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting winner to whatever value is contained in cVoteA[iv]. And then using that value as an index into cNameA. This is dangerous and likely to crash, depending on how you have initialized your array cVoteA.

The array index references the name and number of votes for a specific candidate at that index. You can't use the number of votes (stored in cVoteA[]) as an index into the name array cNameA.

In winner you should be storing the INDEX, not the value from cVoteA[]:

```
public static String WinnerM(String cNameA[], int cVoteA[], int thresh, int winner)
{
    int total = 0; //Declare the total variable and set it to 0
    int iv = 0;
    for (iv = 0; iv < cVoteA.length; iv++)
    {
        if(cVoteA[iv] > total)
        {
            winner = iv;
        }
    }
    return cNameA[winner]; //Return candidate name
}
```

Comment: It still prints only the first name :s

Comment: Because you are still using println("winner = " + cNameA[winner]), outside the function call. You set winner to 0 and it is not changed by the function call. Use the return value from the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function return the index of the winner, not his name.

```
public static int WinnerM(int cVoteA[])
{
    int iv, winner = largest = 0;
    for (iv = 0; iv < cVoteA.length; iv++)
    {
        if(cVoteA[iv] > largest)
        {
            largest = cVoteA[iv];
            winner = iv;
        }
    }
    return winner;
}

//FIND WINNER

    int winner = WinnerM(cVoteA);

    System.out.println("Winner     " + "          " + cNameA[winner]);

//
```